# 'A' record for dynamic link vs normal hosted website

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase, amazon-route53, firebase-dynamic-links

we have a domain on AWS - that has a 'A' record linked to a particular alias. We are planning to use the same domain for dynamic links on firebase. Firebase has given us a couple of IP addresses which we want to add to our A records on AWS.

I have a couple of questions here :

1. How do we add two static IPs along with an alias in Simple Routing ? I know we can use multivalue answer record set for this but I have the next question on that front.
2. If we use multivalue answer record, how will we make sure that the request for normal website content is always routed to the alias in the first 'A' record and the one for dynamic link is always routed to the second 'A' record ? Please look at the image url below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7APaQ.jpg)

Comment: I believe there is no way to distinguish between the two using Route53. I know it's not the answer you were looking for, but consider creating a subdomain for the deep links, which should be the easiest and most practical alternative.